# Developing for jailbroken iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak, sign

I'm new to programming for iOS and on MacOs, so excuse me for asking a dumb question here.

But I wonder if I really need the iOS developer license or that I can jailbreak my iPad and then just develop for it. Would I be able to use the free version of Xcode with the latter?
Or would I still need to get the license to get the iOS Xcode?

Not that I am into warez, but jailbreaking is legal (where I live), so if I would buy the developer license just to publish apps, I would postpone this untill necessary.

Comment: I believe you have to have a developer account to create a provisioning profile for your iDevice in order to run apps on it. You can build apps for the simulator with the free version of xcode, but I'm pretty sure you still need the developer account to for testing on your iPad (even if jailbroken). Of course, maybe there is a way for you to install the app without the provisioning profile, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an app called Jailcoder, which I discovered in a now deleted post (https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34802/8699). It sets up Xcode and indvidual project files so that the resulting apps can be run on jailbroken iOS devices without a developer's license (and can apparently revert the changes, though I haven't tried this).

More info on jailcoder: http://web.archive.org/web/20130306030505/http://oneiros.altervista.org/jailcoder/

Comment: Your link is now dead and the official website is down too, but a bit of google search and we're happy (try a bunch of pages). Very useful app.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the free version of the developer license which will allow you to develop iOS apps on the simulator. The only downside is that some hardware interfaces (core location, gyro/accelerometer, etc) cannot be tested with the simulator. If you don't need that stuff immediately just use the free license and then purchase the real license when you are ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

[Beginning Jailbroken iPhone Development](http://brandontreb.com/beginning-jailbroken-ios-development-getting-the-tools/) is a two-part article that tells you how to get started. I haven't tried this, but it does look like it starts with setting up your tools through how to launch the jailbroken app on your device. There is a link to the second part of the article. There is no mention of needing a developer's license at all.

The article also refers to a tool called Theos, which simplifies the whole process.

I hope this helps.